# sql server using where with if else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have store procedure which is receiving gender value that could be male, female or both, i need to be able to condition my where clause so that if the @gender value is 'both' then select should return male and female, but if gender is either male or female then then @gender value should be selected. i tried below query both it is giving incorrect syntax error for where.

select 
FirstName,SecondName,Gender,race,Height,HeightUnit, Weight,WeightUnit,EmailAdd
from volunteers

```
IF @gender = 'both'
BEGIN

    WHERE Gender = 'male' or Gender ='female' 

END ELSE BEGIN

    WHERE Gender = @gender
END
```

Comment: I don't get the wild card used in Male%... As far as I know there are only two gender either male or female...

Comment: You cant put an IF statement in a WHERE Clause like that... either you use Dynamic SQL which would be an overkill or you use a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an `if` to have a conditional `where` clause.  Instead, just put the logic in the query:

Based on the OP, you want:

```
select FirstName, SecondName, Gender, race, Height, HeightUnit,
       Weight, WeightUnit, EmailAdd
from volunteers
where @gender = 'both' and gender in ('male', 'female') or
      gender = @gender;
```

Alternatively, this might be sufficient:

```
select FirstName, SecondName, Gender, race, Height, HeightUnit,
       Weight, WeightUnit, EmailAdd
from volunteers
where @gender = 'both' or
      gender = @gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok If I am understanding you correctly... try it this way:

```
select FirstName,SecondName,
CASE When @Gender = 'both' then 'Male, Female' else @Gender as Gender  END
,race,Height,HeightUnit, Weight,WeightUnit,EmailAdd from volunteers
```

You can tweak exactly what you want it to say but this is the idea

**UPDATE:** per the comments this is the full procedure that he is using:

```
    Create PROCEDURE spSelectUpdateTrial 

    @gender nvarchar(50), 
    @minage nvarchar(150), 
    @maxage nvarchar(150), 
    @country nvarchar(50), 
    @smoking nvarchar (50), 
    @smoke nvarchar(50), 
    @nct nvarchar(50) AS 

    select FirstName,
SecondName,
CASE 
When @Gender = 'both' 
then 'Male, Female' 
else @Gender
END 
as 
Gender,
race,
Height,
HeightUnit,
Weight,
WeightUnit,
EmailAdd 
from volunteers
```

Note I added an END after `else @gender`

Comment: I dont know how the @gender is used here, so maybe you really mean Gender (coming from the database) as opposed to `@Gender` which I assume is a parameter being passed in.

Comment: yes the ATgender is the parameter for the sp, i have used for code but getting error near 'as Gender'                                     Create PROCEDURE spSelectUpdateTrial
    ATgender nvarchar(50),
 ATminage nvarchar(150),
 ATmaxage nvarchar(150),
 ATcountry nvarchar(50),
 ATsmoking nvarchar (50),
    ATsmoke nvarchar(50),
 ATnct nvarchar(50)

    
AS 



select 
FirstName,SecondName,CASE When ATGender = 'both' then 'Male, Female' else ATGender as Gender,race,Height,HeightUnit, Weight,WeightUnit,EmailAdd
from volunteers

Comment: You are missing and END after @Gender

Comment: i have added end could run the query successfully, the only thing is if 'both' is passed as ATGender then i want both male and female rows to be displayed. With your code however the gender column contains Male,Female for every row it should be like 1st row - - - male -  2nd row - - - female - 3rd row - - - male - etc

Comment: my bad for not being clear but gordons approach seemed have done the trick